# Can you identify this belt/legs

Tags: part-identification

Can anyone identify [this pair of legs](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?%2Fforums%2Ftopic%2F88577-arthas-menethil-prince-of-lorderon%2F). I looked at all the chima legs and legs with the word 'lion' in them, couldn't find it.

Comment: Could you include image directly here? Images on a linked forum ails to open for me.

Comment: Why are your posts randomly being downvoted? About three of your posts have all been downvoted within the same time, very strange. I truly don't think this question is eligible for a downvote, here, I'll give you an upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that same Eurobricks thread it says:

> The legs (not hips) are from the Fantasy Era Crown King.

This is the [minifigure](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=cas422&name=Fantasy%20Era%20-%20Crown%20King,%20No%20Cape,%20Printed%20Legs&category=%5BCastle%5D%5BFantasy%20Era%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) this refers to:

[image]

For completeness, the torso (but not the arms) and the hips come from [this Laval minifigure](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=loc049&name=Laval&category=%5BLegends%20of%20Chima%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from the Chima theme:

[image]